# Is Xcode xcframework more secure from reverse engineering than a static lib .a?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild, xcframework

We have an Xcode static lib with a single Swift public access func and a bunch of private C.

Would it be less vulnerable to reverse engineering to use "xcodebuild ... -library ..." to import the static lib into an Xcode framework (ie. xcframework) project and then release the framework than it would be to release the static lib folder with the .a and .swiftmodule?

Answer (score 1):

No. An xcframework that is built from a static library is literally just that library in a subdirectory. From a reverse-engineering point of view, they are completely equivalent.